# Adding large numbers returns strange, large numbers

Tags: fortran, fortran90, addition, largenumber

I am trying to do some calculations in Fortran that looks like:

```
large number (order E40) - large number (order E40)
```

I should get back zero. Most of the time it works, but in a couple of cases I'm getting weird numbers. One answer Fortran gave me was `-1E20`. Another weird answer I got was `32768`, which is `2^15`, oddly enough.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: You must show your code and show which result youbget for which input and which input you want instead. Don't forget to show the definitions of your variables.

Comment: Do you mean addition (as in the title), or subtraction (as in the pseudo-code)?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without actual code, but...

This is only to be expected if the numbers are sufficiently similar. While `1e20` is pretty large compared to `1` or `2`, it is pretty small compared to `1e40`.

In fact, even with double precision, you only have [15-17 digits of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Considering that, the values you get are below the accuracy possible with numbers in the range of `1e40`.

What you see is numerical noise.

---

[ Another possibility, of course, is that you are trying to do this in single precision. This is not possible (max. exponent ~38) and anything might happen. ]

Comment: Right. Sorry, I should have formulated my question a little better -- I have two very large numbers that I need to subtract. When I do the subtraction by hand, the answer is zero. Fortran, however, spits out a number that is definitely not zero--not even close. I realize that this is an issue with precision. All my variables are currently double precision, and I'm wondering if there's a way to increase that. After looking around on the internet, I've tried real*16 and real*10, but neither of those work.

Comment: @naomig You should edit the question, then. Maybe you should take some time to read [ask]... Improving the question might remove the down-votes and close-votes.